Is there a way to get PASS results from pytest.mark.xfail marked tests instead of XPASS?
I have, for example, a scenario like the one below:
import pytest


class SomeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message = "Some Error Occured"):
        super().__init__(message)


@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=SomeException)
def test_something():
    pass

Now this will XFAIL all SomeException cases, FAIL all other exceptions and XPASS all other cases where the test successfully completes (since xfail_strict = False).
But what I want it for all such XPASS scenarios to be a PASS, since this is not a flaky situation but the actual behaviour. If anything, xfail is just used here to handle the potential expected failure cases than to tell the test itself is supposed to be a failure in all cases.
Is it possible to turn the XPASS results to PASS? perhaps via conditions?
FWIW I don't necessarily need to use xfail, as long as it lets me handle this potential error scenario. Are there better ways to do this, other than hacking around too much?

My approach so far was:
Write one test which you expect to pass if and only if the code under test raises SomeException.
Use pytest.raises as a context manager to check if the exception is raised:
import pytest


class SomeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message = "Some Error Occured"):
        super().__init__(message)

def function_under_test():
    raise SomeException()  # stand-in for scenario that raises exception

def test_exception():
    with pytest.raises(SomeException) as exception_info:
        function_under_test()
    assert "Some Error Occured" == exception_info.value


Then write tests for all the scenarios which you expect to NOT raise the exception. Now all your tests should PASS.

I did considere pytest.raises but unfortunately it does not fit my use case. The function I have calls an api which according to the current circumstances run certain actions and sometimes there are lack of availability for the requested thing, in which case the exception is raised but is a valid thing. This is arbitrary and could happen anytime.

@Operator What you want to do here then is mock the API. Your tests should be stable and not dependent on behavior external to the code under test. So you would do one test where you simulate the API returning the result correctly, and one where you simulate the API returning a "Resource not found" or whatever error you are getting. You do not perform actual API calls during your test, just to your pseudo-API, which is hard-coded to return certain results with certain inputs.

It's not that this wasn't considered, rather these are intergration tests and absolutely reliant on the current state of the API (or to rephrase, whether we are following the API in the correct way). The whole purpose is to test whether we are getting from the API what we are supposed to get. For unit tests what you mentioned should the way, but unfortunately that does no work here.

One option is to utilize a hook wrapper to inspect the exception raised and act accordingly
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True) 
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    output = yield

    if output.excinfo:
            # Additional logic to match to SomeException
            pytest.skip()

